# How should we use ClientIDMode property that comes with asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, clientid, modesetting

How should we use ClientIDMode property that comes with asp.net 4.0?... When i should i use one over the other clientIdModes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rick Strahl wrote a nice article on this very topic](https://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/54760.aspx):

> One of the more anticipated features
>   of ASP.NET 4.0 – at least for me - is
>   the new ClientIDMode property, which
>   can be used to force controls to
>   generate clean Client IDs that don’t
>   follow ASP.NET’s munged
>   NamingContainer ID conventions.

Comment: [Updated link.](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40)